# Weblogic: Mixed Windows and Linux Domain

Tags: linux, windows, weblogic

The project I am currently working on has a mix of legacy software and new development. The new dev work is being done on Linux and we have created a large domain on the Linux side. However, all of the legacy software must remain on Windows...

I haven't found any documentation indicating a mixed domain is possible although I can't see why the node managers or servers would have a problem communicating.

**Can I add a Windows managed server to my Linux domain**? Has anyone ever tried this? I can leave the domains separate if need be (although management won't be happy) but I was tasked with consolidating everything into a single domain.

If you don't have an exact answer, any links to documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've got this up and running... it wasn't all that bad. Here's what we did:

Create a domain on Linux (NFS)

Add Weblogic .cmd start/stop scripts into `<domain home>/bin` folder

On Windows side:

- Create a symlink under C: to the NFS domain location

  - mklink /D folder_name \\OUR-NFS01\path\to\domain
- Update nodemanager.properties and nodemanager.domains to use the symlink path
- Update nodemanager.properties to use our startManagedWebLogic.cmd for the start script
- Update all of the .cmd files to reference the symlink path to the domain (e.g. DOMAIN_HOME)
- Make sure in nodemanager.properties and .cmd files we reference the correct Windows JAVA_HOME location
- Make sure any paths in the admin console (e.g. log file location) for the Windows managed server also reference the symlink path

That was it. Once we had the Windows nodemanager up and running we were able to start a managed server on the Windows host.

Side Note: We had issues using running the nodemanager as a Windows service when using mapped network drives. The service would not always see that mapped drive. That is why we chose to use a symlink instead (and it seems cleaner to me anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a practical experience with running such mixed-OS domain but I do not see a why it should not conceptually work.

Weblogic runs on Java, so that should work on both platforms.

The only problem that you may experience is that if the domain was created for a particular OS, its startup scripts will either be `.sh` for Linux or e.g. `.cmd` for Windows. In this case, you will probably need to get startup scripts for the particular OS and slightly modify them to match your target domain.

Comment: I think we have the various scripts covered, what I am more worried about is the file system(s). If I add a managed server in Linux it will create it in something like <domain>/servers/<server name>. If I add a Windows server... what happens when it tries to create that directory but Windows can't see it. Those are the kind of worries we have. That said, we'll be trying it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic is [supported on both platforms](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/fusion-certification-100350.html), and startup scripts are also for both windows and linux.

The protocol they communicate is not in any way I know platform specific, so there's no reason for this to not work.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on this however, so you need to just go for it.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent WebLogic documentation is quite clear on this. A domain can mix hardware, operating system and JVM as long as all of them are supported:

[Hardware, Operating System, and JVM Platform Compatibility](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/INTRO/compatibility.htm#CDDHAIJJ)

Oracle does recommend to use homogenous clusters as managed servers are expected to be equivalent to eachother, if this is not the case this may negatively impact load balancing and performance (see the above link).